# Underlying Workings of SelectionKey.interestOps(int ops)

Tags: java, sockets, selector, nio

I understand that Server socket channel is registered to listen for accept, when accepted a channel is registered for read and once read it is registered for write and this is done by adding the relevant keys to the SelectionKey's  interest set using the interestOps method.

However, when we remove some interestOps from a key for e.g `key.interestOps(key.interestOps() & ~SelectionKey.OP_READ);`

What actually happens here? Does this mean that the server will just not listen for any incoming requests to channel belonging to this socket, and the source channel will be oblivious of this decision by the server and might keep on sending data to the server? Or will it somehow inform the channel source of this decision.

In packet switching parlance, is the above operation effectively the same as server receiving packets and just dropping the packet if the interestKeys for the channel this packet belong to have been "unset"

Comment: 'Once read it is registered for write' No. It is registered for write if and only if `write()` returns zero, and deregistered next time it doesn't. Any other usage is incorrect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However, when we remove some interestOps from a key for e.g `key.interestOps(key.interestOps() & ~SelectionKey.OP_READ);`
>
> What actually happens here?

What literally happens is something like:

```
public void interestOps(int interestOps)
{
    this.interestOps = interestOps;
}
```

> Does this mean that the server will just not listen for any incoming requests to channel belonging to this socket

It means that the `Selector` won't trigger any `OP_READ` events if data arrives via the socket. It doesn't mean that data won't be received.

> and the source channel will be oblivious of this decision by the server and might keep on sending data to the server?

If by 'source channel' you mean the peer, it is not advised in anyway, unless the receive buffer fills up at the receiver.

> Or will it somehow inform the channel source of this decision.

No.

> In packet switching parlance, is the above operation effectively the same as server receiving packets and just dropping the packet if the interestKeys for the channel this packet belong to have been "unset".

No.

Comment: So once we remove the interestOps from the key and then after some time add it again, what will happen to all the data that arrived via the socket since then? Will the selector somehow replay it using a queue of sorts or is that data just "lost"?

Comment: It stays in the socket receive buffer, and causes OP_READ events until it is exhausted by reads. OP_READ simply means 'there is data in the socket receive buffer'. TCP never throws away data unless a connecion is reset. The socket receive buffer *is* the queue.